# Python: Complexity of functions with slicing tuples and strings

Tags: python, time, tuples, time-complexity, space

I am unsure of how to derive the time and space complexity for the below two functions.

In the following function, `schedule` is a tuple of strings and `course` is a string. I think the time complexity here is O(n^2) since it is O(n) for each recursion where `schedule[0]` is being sliced and then concatenated to a tuple of length n strings. There are a total of n recursions - hence, O(n*n) = O(n^2).

For the part where the slicing and then the concatenation occurs, is it because I am technically adding each of the element of tuple of strings(`schedule[1:]`) to that one string (`schedule[0]`) and that there are a total of n elements in that tuple?

For space complexity, I think it is also O(n^2) as each time the slicing and the concatenation occurs, a new tuple of space of n is being created. This happens for n recursions and henceforth, O(n*n) = O(n^2).

```
def drop_class(schedule, course):
    if schedule==():
        return ()
    elif schedule[0] == course:
        return schedule[1:]
    else:
        return (schedule[0],) + drop_class(schedule[1:], course)
```

In the following function, `letter` and `word` are both strings. 
I think that the time and space complexity here is also O(n^2) for both respectively for the same reasons in the aforementioned example.

```
def remove(letter, word):
    if word[0] == " ":
        return " "
    if word[0] == letter:
        return remove(letter, word[1:])
    else:
        return word[0] + remove(letter, word[1:])
```

However, I am still unsure if I am approaching the problems in the correct way and would appreciate some guidance over this. Thank you.